# pyodbc "commit" command not recognised in Python 3.2

Tags: python, pyodbc

Has anybody got pyodbc installed with Python 3.2?
I have, and all is well except that the interpreter doesn't recognise "commit()".
Anyone else got the same problem?
Anyone know if I'm doing something wrong?
Thanks,
John R

Comment: Could you post the code where you use `commit()`? This method is called on a Connection object, not in a cursor - it might be the problem.

Comment: [pyodbc 3.0.6](http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/wiki/ReleaseNotes#3.0.6_-_2012-06-25) added `commit` and `rollback` methods for cursors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is an example of my code using commit() :

```
   cnxn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; Dbq=F:\\computing\\Payroll v2 2\\\employees.accdb')
   cursor = cnxn.cursor()
   cursor.execute("insert into Medication(ID, Doctor, NameOfMedication, Dosage, DateStart, DateEnd, Notes, LastUpdated) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",self.ui.residentComboBox.currentText().split()[0], self.ui.doctorLineEdit.text(), self.ui.nameOfMedicationLineEdit.text(), self.ui.dosageLineEdit.text(), self.ui.dateStartDateEdit.text(), self.ui.dateEndDateEdit.text(), self.ui.notesTextEdit.document().toPlainText(), self.ui.lastUpdatedDateTimeEdit.dateTime().toString("dd/MM/yyyy, hh:mm:ss")) 
   cursor.execute("update Medication set MedEndMonth=? where ((ID=?)) ",month,resID)                
   cnxn.commit()
   self.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found a way round it. Still couldn't get commit() to work but in the pyodbc.connect() function, if "autocommit=True" is included, all the inserts get committed automatically and you don't need to use the commit() function.  e.g.

```
conx = pyodbc.connect("""Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};
                         DBQ=C:\Documents and Settings\Owner\My Documents\
                         Database2.accdb;""", autocommit = True)
```